# The callback of spy is not invoking with sinon and qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit, sinon

For unit testing, I am trying to make fake server with `sinon.js` and `qUnit`, but after invoke the `ajax` method the `callback` of `spy` is not invoking.

That's why third and fourth assertion are not satisfied,

```
ok(callback.called, "spy called once"); //failed
ok(callback.calledWith([{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }]);  //failed
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, Here what I have tried.

```
test("should fetch comments from server", function () {
        var server = this.sandbox.useFakeServer();
        server.respondWith("GET", "/something",
                           [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                            '[{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }]']);


        var callback = this.spy();
        //----^---this is not invoking

        //after invoke below $.ajax() code above callback should be invoked 
        //and 3rd and 4th assertion should be satisfied but not happening.

        $.ajax({
            url: "/something",
            success: callback
         });

        server.respond();
        equal(server.requests.length, 1, "server request length");
        ok(callback.called, "spy called once"); //failed
        ok(callback.calledWith([{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }])); //failed
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGrTK/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a parse error is causing the ajax error handler to run instead of the success handler.  If you fix up the JSON like this...

```
    server.respondWith("GET", "/something",
                       [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                        '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]']);
```

...the test passes.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGrTK/15/).